# Maximizing an Expectation - OR

Tags: optimization, terminology, discrete-optimization, operations-research

In some place I read that one can solve the following problem

$$ \max_{x \in B} \mathbb{E}_{y}\left[ f(x,y) \right] $$

where $x$ is my choice vector and $y$ is a random vector, by simulating $N$ samples, for each sample maximizing the problem as if it was deterministic, but adding the constraint that the optimizer should be the same across samples.

Can someone provide a name for this method? or a reference? I think I read it in a book by Powell, but can't actually find it.

Comment: Is this a nonanticipativity constraint?

Comment: Replacing the expectation by sample average falls under the empirical risk minimization scenario and the general methods are called stochastic optimization methods.